# Why do we say "Er weiß gut Bescheid"? Gut is an adjetive in akk that follows a noun, isn't it?

Tags: grammaticality, adjective-ending

I was doing some exercises and I foud the sentence "er weiß gut Bescheid", I thougt I should say "er weiß guten Bescheid", because it's a stark declension, is that correct?

Comment: Hint: If you encounter an uninflected adjective, it could be an adverb.

Answer (score 9):

No, despite looking similar, this is not the construction as in

> Er weiß guten Rat (He has good advice)

but an adverb stating the degree of his knowledge. So the meaning of *gut* is the same as in

> Ich kenne ihn gut. (I know him well).

So the translation is actually:

*He is well acquainted with that topic.*